# FactoryBot Rails - Using another factory outside a factory definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  origem_account = FactoryBot.create(:legal_person_account)

  Factory :charge_transaction, class: ChargeTransaction, parent: :transaction do
    type { :charge }

    trait :valid_attributes do
      value { 500 }
      origem_account_id { origem_account.id }

      transactional_code { origem_account.id.to_s + '-teste' }
      origem_account_value_before_transaction nil
      destination_account_id nil
      destination_account_value_before_transaction nil
    end

  end
end
```

When I try to run the test I got the following error:

```
ArgumentError:
  Factory not registered: legal_person_account
```

The factory is not identifying another factory outside the **Factory :charge_transaction** definition.

I need this behavior because I need to use the same **:legal_person_account** factory into two fields of this charge_transaction factory, the **:origem_account_id** and **:transactional_code** fields.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do this. I prefer a way that you create `legal_person_account` first and then assign it to `charge_transaction` in your test, ex:

```
let(:origem_account) { create :legal_person_account }
let(:charge_transaction) { create :charge_transaction, origem_account:origem_account }
```

and in your `charge_transaction`, define a callback:

```
factory :charge_transaction do
  ...
  after(:build) { |transaction| transaction.transactional_code =  transaction.origem_account_id.to_s + 
  -teste }
end
```

so `charge_transaction` still uses the same `origem_account`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define or register a factory for `legal_person_account` so within your `FactoryBot.define` block you should add a

```
factory :legal_person_account do
end
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: I have already created the **legal_person_account factory**. It is in the spec/factories folder.

I would like to have its definition in a separated file, as I will do the same usage of **legal_person_account** in other factories.

How could I make the factory see this other **legal_person_account** factory?